# Extract only month and day from date field mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I've a table in a db with some date field with format yyyy-mm-dd

I'm trying to perform a query that take just records with a interval of 3 month from today.

I've done like this

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(myTable.myField, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) = CURDATE()
```

and it works, but my second step is ignore years of my date field and from curdate().

I've tried `EXTRACT` or `DATEFORMAT`, but query doesn't work with those function.

How can I modify my query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is wrong.

Try this instead:

`...WHERE myTable.myField >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH...`

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment:

> with my query i've got all record that have in dateField this date
>   '2016-12-07' (curdate() is today '2016-09-07') and it's fine. but i
>   want that query gives me also date that have 12 on month and 07 on
>   day, ignoring year. Eg. if i have '2016-12-07' and '2014-12-07', my
>   query must give me both records. it's a query that will run every day

```
...WHERE DATE_FORMAT(myTable.myField,'%m-%d') = 
    DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH),'%m-%d')...
```

Comment: i need a interval of 3 month exactly, not more.

I've changed my condition, but this doesn't answer my question about extracting just month and year from date

Comment: You can check the other answer. But if you clarify providing some sample input and expected output then it would be easier to resolve your problem. I am confused about your second requirement.

Comment: with my query i've got all record that have in dateField this date '2016-12-07' (curdate() is today '2016-09-07') and it's fine.

but i want that query gives me also date that have 12 on month and 07 on day, ignoring year.

Eg. if i have '2016-12-07' and '2014-12-07', my query must give me both records.

it's a query that will run every day

Comment: Would you please try with the condition under **Edit** Section?

Answer (score 0):

Use below condition which will find records with a interval of 3 month from today.

```
WHERE myTable.myField = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: If you use `=` then at most one date (3 months back from today) would satisfy the condition.

Comment: Yeah.. That is what SO wants.. I think he wants to fetch record of a single date which should be exactly 3 months of interval from today.